# magento-2-banner-slider block not showing data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to show an image slider in my *Magento e-commerce* home page. I am using [magento-2-banner-slider](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-banner-slider) for the job. I have configured the module as given in the documentation. I have added banner and slider.

I have added the following block code into the home page.

```
{{ block class="Mageplaza\BetterSlider\Block\Slider" template="Mageplaza_BetterSlider::slider.phtml" banner_id="1" }}
```

In my case slider id is 1 so I have not changed the `banner_id`

But the home page is just showing the block code as simple text.

[image]

I am absolutely new to *Magento*. Please bear with me if I am making a simple mistake.

Comment: {{block class="Mageplaza\BetterSlider\Block\Slider" template="Mageplaza_BetterSlider::slider.phtml" banner_id="1"}}

Comment: You should remove the space between open ,close parentheses and letters...the above comment is correct answer

Comment: Thanks. Now the code is not showing. Now I got into another problem that it is not showing anything at all. It should show the slider.